# Getting started with SQL express from a c++ console application

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio-express

Right now I am writing a little c++ console program using VS2010 Express. The next thing I want to do is to access a SQL database from within this program.

I've downloaded SQL server 2008 express. I've managed to set up a little db using the db gui.
My question now is, how do I access this db from within my program. Which header files do I need, how do I connect? About the basic tempering with the db itself I have found many tutorials, but this tiny bit that closes the gap between a program and the connection to the db drives me nuts...  If any one has a nice tip to a tutorial or book, please let me know.

I've also tried to start a new project in VS, and was hoping to find some kind of setup wizard for a "sql project" that would get me one the way but did not find such a wiz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't provide much for SQL connectivity from C++ console applications. There are a number of libraries such as [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) and [DTL](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/) that can help though.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'll have a look at them. You say "Microsoft doesn't provide much for SQL connectivity from C++ console applications" , what kind of "programms" do provide a better connectivity? Lumpi

Comment: @Lumpi: If you use MFC, it has classes for connecting to databases via various routes (ODBC, OLE DB, etc.) If you use .NET, it has database connectivity capabilities as well.

Comment: Thanks! I have snooped around a little more and found http://www.sqlapi.com/, sounds appealing to me so I've decided to give it a try.